# How do I use Meteor's Spacebar helpers within a template?

Tags: templates, meteor

Using meteor, I'm trying to populate a list of tasks within a template.  This will render the tasks just fine:

```
<body>
  <div class="container"> 
    <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
        {{> task}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

This is a separate template task.html

```
<template name="task">
  <li>{{text}}</li>
</template>
```

But once I wrap it in a home template so that I may route it appropriately it no longer shows up:

```
<template name="home">
    <body>
      <div class="container"> 
        <ul>
          {{#each tasks}}
            {{> task}}
          {{/each}}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </body>
</template>
```

Why is this? Below is the client side js, masterLayout template, and router.js.

```
  Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: [
      { text: "This is task 1" },
      { text: "This is sk 2" },
      { text: "This is task 3" }
    ]
  }); 

<template name="masterLayout">
  {{> yield region='nav'}}
  <div id="content">
    {{> yield}}
  </div>
  {{> yield region='footer'}}
</template>


Router.map(function() {
    this.route('home', {
        path: '/',
    });
    this.route('private');
    this.route('testing');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to change the middle word `home` to the template you are referencing.  https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/templates

```
  Template.home.helpers({
    tasks: [
      { text: "This is task 1" },
      { text: "This is sk 2" },
      { text: "This is task 3" }
    ]
  });
```